# error in CGBitmapContextCreate

Tags: iphone, video-streaming, avfoundation, cgbitmapcontextcreate, cgbitmapcontext

i'm trying to create UIImage from the sampleBufferData and here what i have in the console

: CGBitmapContextCreate: invalid data bytes/row: should be at least 1920 for 8 integer bits/component, 3 components, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst.
: CGBitmapContextCreateImage: invalid context 0x0

here is my code

```
// Create a bitmap graphics context with the sample buffer data
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8, 
  bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst); 
// Create a Quartz image from the pixel data in the bitmap graphics context
CGImageRef quartzImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
```

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear on what's wrong. What are you values for the input arguments to `CGBitmapContextCreate`?

Comment: void *baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer); 

    // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer); 
    // Get the pixel buffer width and height
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer); 
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer); 

    // Create a device-dependent RGB color space
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(); 
here is the inputs

Comment: and the imageBuffer is from
// Get a CMSampleBuffer's Core Video image buffer for the media data
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

Comment: You should check these values with the debugger and see if they even make sense. What if the pixel buffer has a different color space or bits per component?

Comment: ok thx Ole for your help i will keep you updated with mu status if you don't mind 
thx again

Comment: that's right the value is 724 but how can i control it ??